# Wifi repeater showing two different BSSIDs

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, repeater

I have a wifi router plus an Edimax repeater.
Problem is that the repeater seems to show two different BSSIDs.

I can't for the life of me figure out how this is happening.
One of the BSSIDs is great and connects perfectly.
However, my computer suddenly flips to the other one which is much weaker and has no internet connection.

It is definitely coming from the repeater because when I unplug it both BSSIDs disappear.
Similarly, when I plug the repeater into my computer with a cable the errant id disappears.

This is what I get when the repeater is not connected directly to the computer:

```
    Network type            : Infrastructure
Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
Encryption              : CCMP
BSSID 1                 : 74:da:38:80:36:ed
     Signal             : 100%
     Radio type         : 802.11n
     Channel            : 1
     Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 11
     Other rates (Mbps) : 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54
BSSID 2                 : c0:ac:54:f7:d9:29
     Signal             : 32%
     Radio type         : 802.11n
     Channel            : 1
     Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 11
     Other rates (Mbps) : 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54
BSSID 3                 : 74:da:38:80:36:df
     Signal             : 18%
     Radio type         : 802.11n
     Channel            : 1
     Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 11
     Other rates (Mbps) : 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54
BSSID 4                 : 74:da:3c:80:36:e0
     Signal             : 18%
     Radio type         : 802.11n
     Channel            : 1
     Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 11
     Other rates (Mbps) : 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54
```

There are 4 entries because I have another repeater plus the base router.

When I plug it in to my computer one of them (the last one) then disappears:

```
Network type            : Infrastructure
Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
Encryption              : CCMP
BSSID 1                 : 74:da:38:80:36:ed
     Signal             : 100%
     Radio type         : 802.11n
     Channel            : 1
     Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 11
     Other rates (Mbps) : 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54
BSSID 2                 : c0:ac:54:f7:d9:29
     Signal             : 52%
     Radio type         : 802.11n
     Channel            : 1
     Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 11
     Other rates (Mbps) : 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54
BSSID 3                 : 74:da:38:80:36:df
     Signal             : 42%
     Radio type         : 802.11n
     Channel            : 1
     Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 11
     Other rates (Mbps) : 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54
```

I could just reset the repeater and try again but am worried that it might make things worse(?).

Comment: Factory reset the repeater, redo the config. Make sure you are using strong passwords on WPA2 psk. They can now be hacked with ease. Use complicated passwords. Minimum 16 digit alphanumerical with uppercase and special characters. If the rouge bssid comes back try updating the firmware on the repeater.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I'll give it a try. 2 in the morning here so unlikely to be tonight. :)

Comment: Cool, let us know if it resolves it. I forgot to mention, disable wps on the main router. It's also been broken and is very easy to crack, even with a strong password a hacker can retrieve a 16 digit key with little to no hassle. The repeater is usually a "dumb" device, repeating everything from layer 1 bit for bit. Including cracking attempts.